# How to get reference of the component associated with ElementRef in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this component in my template:

```xml
<vector-editor  #scaleControl
                [x]="scaleX"
                [y]="scaleY"
                [z]="scaleZ" >               
</vector-editor>
```

The `vector-editor` has the following structure:

```typescript
export class VerticeControlComponent implements OnInit
{
    @Input() x: number;
    @Input() y: number;
    @Input() z: number;

    ...
}
```

In my application I grab a reference to the `#scaleControl` using

```typescript
@ViewChild('scaleControl') scaleControl: ElementRef;
```

Now if I output `scaleControl` to the console I get this result:

[image]

As can be seen, the reference is not null and all the properties of my component are there. I want to access those properties, but in code the actual type of the `scaleControl` is `ElementRef` and not `VectorEditorControl` as seen in the output. Because of this, TypeScript doesn't me allow to use `this.scaleControl.x`.

I also tried to cast `ElementRef` like this

```typescript
var temp = <VectorEditorControl>this.scaleControl
```

but I get an error telling me that I cannot cast `ElementRef` to `VectorEditorControl`

In the end, I tried to access `this.scaleControl.nativeElement` but it's undefined...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You should know the following things about using [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html) property decorator.

It uses the following **Metadata Properties:**

- **selector** - the directive type or the name used for querying.
- **read** - read a different token from the queried elements.

From source code:

```typescript
export interface ViewChildDecorator {
  /**
   * You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive matching 
   * the selector from the
   * view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the selector,
   * the property will be updated.
   *
   * View queries are set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called.
   *
   * **Metadata Properties**:
   *
   * * **selector** - the directive type or the name used for querying.
   * * **read** - read a different token from the queried elements.
   */
  (selector: Type<any>|Function|string, {read}?: {read?: any}): any;
  new (selector: Type<any>|Function|string, {read}?: {read?: any}): ViewChild;
}
```

If you don't provide the `read` parameter, `@ViewChild()` will return the:

- component instance if there is.
- `ElementRef` instance if there is no component applied
- different token from the queried elements if you **set read property**

So if you want to get `ElementRef` from the child that is angular2 component (`VerticeControlComponent`) you need to explicitely tell using `read: ElementRef`:

```typescript
@ViewChild('scaleControl', {read: ElementRef}) scaleControl: ElementRef;
```

And then **inside ngAfterViewInit hook or later** you can write `this.scaleControl.nativeElement` to get DOM element.

### Update

I wrote early:

> - different token from the queried elements if you **set read property**

Now I want to add what exactly we can read:

- **ElementRef**
- **TemplateRef**
- **ViewContainerRef**
- **Provider**

What does `Provider` mean here?

It means that if we defined any provider(in component or directive) on specific element then we can read it.

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
   <h2>I'm child</h2>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'test', useValue: 'x'
    }
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent {

}
```

So in consumer of this component we can write

```typescript
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, { read: 'test' }) providerToken: string;
```

to get value `x`.

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/htfkLjVRJBLGmAMimSrr?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

See also:

- [What are all the valid selectors for ViewChild and ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162473/what-are-all-the-valid-selectors-for-viewchild-and-contentchild/49167289#49167289)

Comment: to get component directly, one can specify type of child instead using it as ElementRef: `@ViewChild('scaleControl') scaleControl: VerticeControlComponent;`

Comment: plus 1 best expanation

Comment: I'm getting the ` Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`  error when I use your way

Comment: @M98 It means you're doing something wrong or you deal with dynamic query. I can't say more without reproduction

Comment: @yurzui I'm trying to imagine in which scenarios I would want to read a providerToken , can you suggest a scenario ?

Comment: @Royi Namir You can take a look at Wizard example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhNo3Wvj6UQ&feature=youtu.be&t=4967

Comment: Can I get supplied content without `<ng-content>` ?

Comment: @yurzui What about triggering `optionSelected`  event programmaticallay using `@ViewChild` etc?

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing I recommend using the following method:

```typescript
@ViewChild('scaleControl') scaleControl: ElementRef<VerticeControlComponent>;
```

You can then have access to **both** the types.

- **ElementRef:** using `scaleControl`
- **VerticeControlComponent:** using `scaleControl.nativeElement`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `scaleControl.nativeElement` gives a native HTML element, not an instance of `VerticeControlComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error two times. Once in my main code and second time in the test code (spec).

Both time it was some reference missing. Angular compiler(transpiler) does not show any error during compilation but later on, quietly does not provide reference of the

1. First time I got this error in the main code abc.component.ts. I remember that this time, we included the references required for this child correctly in this abc.component.ts. This child component was coming from another module. The error was resolved only after this child component was not included in the module.ts file

   declarations: [VectorEditorComponent,....],
2. Second time we faced this in spec file. I was trying to verify some expectation that a property of the child component should be set. I was not getting instance of the child component but getting ElementRef instead. Here again, there was no compilation error. The problem was slightly different here. I had used No_Errors_Schema. So, although we had not included the component in the spec file, angular did not complain, but instead set ElementRef instead of the child component. The error went away when we imported the module and provided this in the testbed setup of the spec file.

In the second case I can understand that it was due to no error schema. But in the first case, I think Angular team needs to improve. There is no hint whatsoever about why component was not provided but ElementRef is provided.