# @ViewChild angular 2 not working width ion-textarea

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to get the value of ion-textarea inside component in Ionic 2 but I have always this error

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

**Code HTML:**

```
<ion-textarea   #preferences id="preferences" placeholder="Veuillez mentionner vos préferences"></ion-textarea>
```

**component .ts:**

```
@ViewChild('preferences') m_preferences;
let preferences : this.m_preferences.nativeElement.value;
```

Comment: Have you tried `@ViewChild('preferences', { read: ElementRef })`?

Comment: Not working: I got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: ElementRef is not defined

Comment: Just import it `import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core`

Comment: Yes  I did that but still not working

Comment: Are you sure you want to get ElementRef?

Comment: where in your component are you calling let preferences : this.m_preferences.nativeElement.value;?

Comment: I want to get the value of ion-textarea. I put in html just textarea and it's work perfectly but widht ion-textarea not working

Comment: Inside a function : public addProduct(){ let preferences = this.m_preferences.nativeElement.value; ........}

Comment: can you show the whole HTML Code ?

Comment: <ion-textarea  #preferences placeholder="Veuillez mentionner vos préferences"></ion-textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply template reference variable on component element then by default you will get a component instance.

[How to get reference of the component associated with ElementRef in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203)

In your case you applied preferences to ion-textarea component. It's `TextInput` component that has `value` property

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/fed4fd95d2545c324c45d891b837e2bcc4ded79d/src/components/input/input.ts#L144

So you should simple do like this:

```
import { TextInput } from 'ionic-angular';
...
@ViewChild('preferences') m_preferences: TextInput;

addProduct() {
  console.log(this.m_preferences.value);
}
```

I also prepared **[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kxg75b?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**

You can also do it without ViewChild:

```
<ion-textarea #preferences ...></ion-textarea>
<button (click)="addProduct(preferences.value)">Add product</button>

addProduct(value) {
  alert(value) 
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-eeg4ah?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**

If you deal with angular forms then consider @GreyBeardedGeek answer

Comment: @user3033938 Consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: While this will work, I believe that the more correct way to do this is to bind the ion-textarea's value to a component property, using ngModel, instead of using @ViewChild. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

Note that  must load its value from the value or [(ngModel)] attribute. Unlike the native  element,  does not support loading its value from the textarea's inner content.

So, what you are trying to do is not.supported.
You should bind a property to the control  instead.

Comment: Here's @yurzui's stackblitz updated show the correct way to do it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3fvd11?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: `must load its value from the value or [(ngModel)] attribute` In my solution i read it from **the value** not from nativeElement. I don't want to import FormsModule in my @NgModule