# How to retrieve HTML elements (besides input fields) when using @ViewChild

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have this form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm">    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ngModel id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>    
    ...
</form>
```

Inside the .ts file I reach the form with `@ViewChild("form", {static:false}) myForm: NgForm`

Now, starting from the field **myForm**, what is the best/easy way to reach and manipulate the other HTML elements inside the form, for example, the label element?

Thank you.

Comment: You won't necessarily have what you want on the NgForm component itself. Have a read at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203 .

If you want children elements, try one of these 2 SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540610/how-to-get-elementref-reference-from-ngmodel-formcontrol-in-ngform-in-angular-4 .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642547/is-it-possible-to-get-native-element-for-formcontrol

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Jojofoulk; I read the articles but it's not clear what you are suggesting to me. Should I add read:ElementRef to @ViewChild()?? In that case I won't have a NgForm anymore and, for example, the validation system of Angular won't work.