# How to disable button when this length satisfies

Tags: angular

How to disable the below div when this length condition satisfies. Please check and help me..

```html
<div *ngIf="setUpWizardForm.get('projectTitle').value && slpPlat && (setUpWizardForm.get('projectTitle').value.length + slpPlat.length) > 50" >
    <span 
        class="error-message" 
        style="padding-left:15px;"
    > 
        Project Name - maximum of 50 characters allowed 
    </span>
</div>

<!-- Here want to disable that div in below button. Please help -->

<button 
    href="javascript:void(0);" 
    class="slm-user-action-btn" 
    [disabled]='setUpWizardForm.invalid || !projectNameFilled' 
    *ngIf="currentSlide==3" 
    type="button" 
    (click)="projectConfigured(templateInProcess)"
> 
    Configure
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable button when characters exceeds in projectTitle field and using suffix as slpPlat we can do in below manner :

1. Keep a **onChange()** function on your input type projectTitle. So it will be something like `<input name="projectTitle" onChange="checkFieldLen()"` />
2. Now in this function as well as on **ngAfterViewInit()** hook need to calculate length for the input fields.
3. You can access input element in your **.ts file** using ElementRef ([How to get ElementRef reference from NgModel FormControl in NgForm in Angular 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540610/how-to-get-elementref-reference-from-ngmodel-formcontrol-in-ngform-in-angular-4))
4. Now check the length including suffix at both the places and toggle the boolean variable to enable/disable the button

Comment: Actually When I type the 50 chars above, the button will disable. I wrote 50 chars condition, that one is working fine. Now I want to disable button if it is exceeds 50 chars in the above mentioned and existing code.  please help

Comment: So what we understand is you want to disable button when characters exceeds 50 right ?

Comment: yes correct. Please help

Comment: Can you please give some more detail(code) of setUpWizardForm and projectNameFilled so we can help in exact manner

Comment: setUpWizardForm is form name and projectNameFilled-they took bolean variable for other validation.     <form [formGroup]="setUpWizardForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

Comment: here unable to post the full code. please access me chat

Comment: Can you please tell your angular version.. it is 2+ right ?

Comment: anguar 8 version

Comment: Can you please give the input field name or ngModel name in which you are writing 50 characters...as we are modifying the answer to help you in better manner..

Comment: projectTitle and slpPlat  -->slpPlat  is suffix name and projectTitle is input field. we need to combine these 2. wen combine these 2 not exceeds 50 char

Comment: Can you please refer our edited answer as to how to resolve your problem

Comment: very confusing..

Comment: If as an summary if you see attach the ElementRef with the input and calculate the length in ts file and based on it refer boolean variable. I hope this may help you... You can have a look at reference link added in answer.

Comment: I checked but not getting

Comment: Okay we will try to make it more simplified and try to get back. Thank you