# What are all the valid selectors for ViewChild and ContentChild?

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of the valid selectors I can use to access child components / DOM elements via `@ViewChild` and `@ContentChild`.

Say I have a child `HelloComponent`:

I know I can add a template `#ref` and query for it, like so:

```
<hello #myHello></hello>

@ViewChild('myHello') myHello: HelloComponent;
```

Or I can look for that component directly (without the template `#ref`):

```
@ViewChild(HelloComponent) myHello: HelloComponent;
```

In [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21734), it is mentioned that one can use the following selectors:

> we are currently supporting a sub-set of CSS selectors:
>   * element selectors
>   * attribute selectors (including values)
>   * :not(...) pseudo-selector
>   * combination of the above (including ,)

But when I tested these in Stackblitz to verify ([here's the link to that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ltsb4m)), I couldn't actually get any of the first three to work. *(Check the console to see `undefined` for the types of selectors I couldn't get working. I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong with those selectors or if the actual list is different.)*

So, which selectors will work? Also, is the list the same for `@ViewChild`, `@ContentChild`, `@ViewChildren`, and `@ContentChildren`?

Comment: AFAIK, the comment in the issue is wrong, and talks about `@Component` and `@Directive` selectors, but not about `@ViewChild` selectors.

Comment: Excelent. I have the same question.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

First of all, as @JB Nizet has already mentioned in comments **[the comment in the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21734#issuecomment-360197311) is wrong**: it has nothing to do with query selector but rather refers to [directive selector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c089c1d931c0ea35591837706de205a75a61ccb/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L80-L112).

Let's examine what kind of selectors we can use for queries.

Angular documentation [states](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildDecorator#members) that for queries:

> **selector** - the directive type or the name used for querying.

### The directive type

Seems it should be clear for anyone that **(1) we can query any classes adorned by `@Component` or `@Directive` decorator**.

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'some-comp',
  template: '...'
})
export class SomeComp {}

@Directive({
  selector: '[someDir]'
})
export class SomeDir {}

@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `
    <some-comp someDir></some-comp>
  `
})
export class HostComp {
  @ViewChild(SomeComp) someComp: SomeComp;
  @ViewChild(SomeDir) someDir: SomeDir;
}
```

### The name used for querying

As for me this is confusing description.

As it turned out the name here is **(2) the name of [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) which is a string**:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `
    <some-comp #someComp></some-comp>
  `
})
export class HostComp {
  @ViewChild('someComp') someComp: SomeComp;
}
```

we could end up here but it's time to take a look at angular source code and dive a bit deeper.

### Hidden behavior

Let's look at [the code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c089c1d931c0ea35591837706de205a75a61ccb/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L1118-L1136) that angular compiler uses to read query metadata:

```typescript
private _queryVarBindings(selector: any): string[] { return selector.split(/\s*,\s*/); }

private _getQueryMetadata(q: Query, propertyName: string, typeOrFunc: Type|Function):
      cpl.CompileQueryMetadata {
  let selectors: cpl.CompileTokenMetadata[];
  if (typeof q.selector === 'string') {
    selectors =
        this._queryVarBindings(q.selector).map(varName => this._getTokenMetadata(varName));
  } else {
    if (!q.selector) {
      this._reportError(
          syntaxError(
              `Can't construct a query for the property ...`),
          typeOrFunc);
      selectors = [];
    } else {
      selectors = [this._getTokenMetadata(q.selector)];
    }
}
```

From the preceding code we can conclude that:

- if selector is a string divided by `,` then we can construct more than one selector.
- on the other hand if selector is not a string then we can get only one selector
- compiler uses `this._getTokenMetadata` method to extract information from passed selector but it's the same method that is used for extracting provider metadata https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4c089c1d931c0ea35591837706de205a75a61ccb/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L1073-L1077

Let’s apply our learnings from above code.

We **(3) can query several values by using several template reference variables divided by `,`**:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  template: '...'
})
export class A {}

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  template: '...'
})
export class B {}

@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `
    <a #a></a>
    <b #b></b>
  `
})
export class HostComp {
  @ViewChildren('a, b') components;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.components); // [A, B]
  }
}
```

**(4) Provider defined on a component or directive can be queried.** (see also example added by @Ilia Volk)

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  template: '...',
  providers: [SomeService]
})
export class A {}

@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `<a></a>`
})
export class HostComp {
  @ViewChild(SomeService) someService: SomeService;
}
```

Since string can be a token for providers we can **(5) query several providers that were defined through string token**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  providers: [{ provide: 'tokenA', useValue: 'TokenAValue' }],
  template: '...'
})
export class A { }

@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  providers: [{ provide: 'tokenB', useValue: 'TokenBValue' }],
  template: '...'
})
export class B { }

@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `
    <a #a></a>
    <b #b></b>
  `
})
export class HostComp {
  @ViewChildren('tokenA, tokenB') stringTokenProviders;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.stringTokenProviders); // ['TokenAValue', 'TokenBValue']
  }
}
```

The next our stop is the place in core package where [angular returns us the value of particular query](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/core/src/view/query.ts#L176-L193):

```typescript
export function getQueryValue(
    view: ViewData, nodeDef: NodeDef, queryValueType: QueryValueType): any {
  if (queryValueType != null) {
    // a match
    switch (queryValueType) {
      case QueryValueType.RenderElement:
        return asElementData(view, nodeDef.nodeIndex).renderElement;
      case QueryValueType.ElementRef:
        return new ElementRef(asElementData(view, nodeDef.nodeIndex).renderElement);
      case QueryValueType.TemplateRef:
        return asElementData(view, nodeDef.nodeIndex).template;
      case QueryValueType.ViewContainerRef:
        return asElementData(view, nodeDef.nodeIndex).viewContainer;
      case QueryValueType.Provider:
        return asProviderData(view, nodeDef.nodeIndex).instance;
    }
  }
}
```

`RenderElement` in the code above is some internal token that we can't query.

`ElementRef` can be queried through template reference variable or by using **[read option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203)**

**(6) TemplateRef can be queried through `selector`**:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'host-comp',
  template: `
    <ng-template></ng-template>
  `
})
export class HostComp {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;
}
```

and of course as well as `ViewContainerRef` through `read` option.

`Provider` can be obtained by using `read` option or through selector as I've described in the middle of this answer.

Comment: what is the use case for `(4) Provider defined on a component or directive can be queried.`

Answer (score 17):

IN short **View child**
You can use anglular directive, component selector, reference variable

[image]