# QueryList of inherited components in Angular

Tags: angular

i have the following components: Base component A. Components B and C are inherited from A.

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'A',
  template: `<div>A</div>`
})
export class A {}

@Component({
  selector: 'B',
  template: `<div>B</div>`
})
export class B extends A {}

@Component({
  selector: 'C',
  template: `<div>C</div>`
})
export class C extends A {}
```

And there is a component class which contains all of the A, B and C components:

```typescript
<A></A>
<B></B>
<C></C>
```

My question is **how can i get the querylist of all A, B and C**?

I've tried

```typescript
@ViewChildren(A) components: QueryList<A>;
```

but it gives me only `A` component.

Here's also [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ew4qv?p=preview) that demonstrates the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Eldho, im sure you are a experienced Angular developer. How can i make my problem clearer to you?

Comment: I have the example in Plunkr. Couldn't run it. Hope you guys can understand what i want to do. http://plnkr.co/edit/O8sloL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to get all components throught `@ViewChildren(A)` query you should define `A` provider on each of your derived components:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'A',
  template: `<div>A</div>`
})
export class A {}

@Component({
  selector: 'B',
  template: `<div>B</div>`,
  providers: [{ provide: A, useExisting: B }]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class B extends A {}

@Component({
  selector: 'C',
  template: `<div>C</div>`,
  providers: [{ provide: A, useExisting: C }]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class C extends A {}
```

Later in your parent component you should write something like:

```typescript
@ViewChildren(A) components: QueryList<A>;
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/sAyqAFGmMAoQUO5mnHWx)**

See also:

- [What are all the valid selectors for ViewChild and ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162473/what-are-all-the-valid-selectors-for-viewchild-and-contentchild/49167289#49167289)

Comment: Thank you yurzui. This is the solution i am looking for.

Comment: If you are loading inherited component inside ng-content use @ContentChildren to query...