# Angular 2+ - Querying for dynamic dom elements

Tags: angular, dom

I have a component which allows creating buttons and textboxes on click of corresponding button.  Is there any way of accessing newly added elements?  I have tried using ViewChildren and subscribing to the changes, but of no use.  I tried with injecting elementref in constructor, but I want the ViewChildren to work properly i.e. the querylist to be updated.

Here is the link for the stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w69vso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
@ViewChildren("input")
```

means that you're going to query elements which have `#input` template reference variables but you use `<input #templateTextBox` so i would try:

```
@ViewChildren("templateTextBox")
```

instead.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxfgqu?file=src/app/view-container-ref-demo.component.ts)**

See also:

- [What are all the valid selectors for ViewChild and ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162473/what-are-all-the-valid-selectors-for-viewchild-and-contentchild)

Comment: That's really silly of me :|  But is there any way of accessing the element by type.. i.e. get all the buttons using the ViewChildren?

Comment: We can't query by type but you can create directive which will have selector `button` and inject ElementRef in constructor and then just use `@ViewChildren(ThatDirective)`