# Angular 5 access divs list using @ViewChildren

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

I want to fetch all divs starting with the id 'div'. To do so, i use @ViewChildren but i'm not able to access the divs because i have an empty array , why ?

My template

```
<div id="div-1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div-2">Div 2</div>
<input type="button" (click)="getDivs()">
```

Component

```
@ViewChildren('div') divs: QueryList<any>;
divList : any[];

getDivs(){ 
   this.divList = this.divs.filter(x => x.id.lastIndexOf('div-', 0) === 0);  
   console.log(this.divList);  
      // this.divList return an empty array but i should have two results  
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As mentioned in [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167289/1009922), the valid selectors for `ViewChildren` include component types, directive types, and template reference variables. You cannot retrieve DOM elements with `ViewChildren` using CSS selectors like HTML element types (e.g. `div`) or class names.

One way to make it work in your case is to generate the `div` elements with an `ngFor` loop, and associate a template reference variable `#divs` to them:

```
<div #divs *ngFor="let item of [1,2]" [id]="'div-' + item">Div {{item}}</div>
<button (click)="getDivs()">Get divs</button>
```

You can then retrieve them in code with `ViewChildren`, using the template reference variable:

```
@ViewChildren("divs") divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

getDivs() {
  this.divs.forEach((div: ElementRef) => console.log(div.nativeElement));
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng4-loading-spinner-fdqjxc) for a demo.

Comment: I'm using Angular 8, and I needed to modify the `@ViewChildren` statement as follows: 
`@ViewChildren("divs", { read: ElementRef }) divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve needed result by creating custom directive and querying it like this:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, ViewChildren, Component, AfterViewInit, QueryList } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({selector: 'table th'})
export class DatatableHeadersDirective {
  nativeElement: HTMLTableHeaderCellElement = null;
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.nativeElement = el.nativeElement;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'selctorname',
  templateUrl: 'htmlURL',
  styleUrls: ['styleURL'],
})
export class AwesomeDatatableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(DatatableHeadersDirective) children: QueryList<DatatableHeadersDirective>;;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.children.map(directive => directive.nativeElement))
  }
}
```