# Add class to one div and remove this class from others by click in Angular

Tags: angular

1. It's just simple divs with text
2. I don't need and don't want use/create other components
3. And without querySelectors
4. Number of elements might be more then 50.
5. Text can be defferent, cities names, for example

Is there a way for

- get all elements with `link` class
- add by clicking to one of them `active` class to target
- and remove `active` class from others
  So, we have 3 same divs, but with `active` class only one.

__

Also, I need to chane active class for another 3 elements - `image` class

This is generaly tabs. But with very simple layout:

```
      <div class="links">
        <div class="link active">
          Link 1
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          Link 2
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          Link 3
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="images">
        <div class="image active">
          Image 1
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          Image 2
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          Image 3
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

component HTML:

```
<div class="links">
  <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]" class="link" [class.active]="clickedIndex === i" (click)="clickedIndex = i"> Link {{ i }} </div>
</div>
```

component class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
})
export class AppComponent {
  clickedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Text will be names of cities. For example London, Moscow, New York. And images with this city in another block. 
Also, there can be 50 cities.

Comment: sounds good, what is your question ?

Comment: As I can see 1) Text to div adds with loop. Now It can be only Link <and some number>. But I need defferent fixed words - London, Moscow, etc. 2) If i need 50 links, then I need to add array like *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 and till 50]" ?

Comment: And also, main question is - is ther a good, simple way to get elemets by class like in pure JS - querySelector('.link') = and then operate with element as I want?

Comment: how can I remove active class from element if I click on active? So I need all of them without active class.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do like @Stavm suggested in his answer (upvoted it), but since you have an array of cities (or different strings) you should just extract the index he mentioned a bit differently. An example:

Say in your component you have an array: `public cities = ['London', 'Moscow', 'Stockholm', ...];`

You can get the index in the for loop like this: `let i = index`;

```
<div class="links">
  <div *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index" class="link" [class.active]="clickedIndex === i" (click)="clickedIndex = i">{{city}} </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE:

After your comments I add an update that will come closest to a query selector. You could consider using `@ViewChildren`. Check [the official Angular documentation on `@ViewChildren` here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). Also checkout the example given in [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016746/1697459). In your example it would be something like this:

In your component:

```
@ViewChildren("linkDivs") linkDivs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChildren("imageDivs") imageDivs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

In your template:

```
<div class="links">
  <div #linkDivs *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index" class="link">{{city}}</div>
</div>

<div class="images">
  <div #imageDivs *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index" class="link">{{image}}</div>
</div>
```

Now you get an array with the `ElementRef` to all link divs in that variable in your component and in the template you can grab it with `linkDivs[i]`. Not sure what exactly you want to do with it further though. I leave that up to you.

Comment: So, in general, there is no simple way to get elemets by class like in pure JS - querySelector('.link') - get some array and then do stuff?

Comment: I would say it is the wrong approach, since `querySelector('.link')` will be executed after the DOM has been rendered. In the example you add the class before the view is rendered so IMO it is a better solution. But if you want something like that you could have a look at `@ViewChildren`. Check [the offical Angular documentation here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description)

Comment: @Spawnet As an addition to the comment above; you could checkout [the example given in another answer on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016746/1697459).

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to do with it further though. - simple tabs: when you click to London => image with London.jpg showed. And the same action for the rest 50 cities.