# How to bind elementref selector from an object to html in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dynamic, binding

I want to bind an elementref from an object to my html in angular. What I tried is:

```
<div #[sec_variable] ></div> OR <div #sec_variable ></div>
```

and get it from @ViewChild() but it says its null.

```
<div class="nav-item" *ngFor="let input of inputs">
  <div #[input.name] /></div>
</div>
```

AND

```
 @ViewChild('image',{static:true,read:ElementRef}) img?

 ngOnInit(): void {

  const label = this.renderer.createElement('label');
  this.renderer.setAttribute(label, 'for', 'image');
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.img.nativeElement, label)
 }
```

BUT it is not working. How can I use it dynamicaly

Comment: you can not, you need use ViewChildren and get the QueryList: `@ViewChildren('mydiv') list:QueryList<ElementRef>`. But be careful, you can not access in ngOnInit, else in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

Somenting like

```
@ViewChild('inputEmail') inputEmail!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
```

and

```
<input #inputEmail>
```

And by the way in your case, static is not true since the element you are querying for is being created dynamically by ngFor directive.

Comment: u mean #inputEmail in a var driven from an object not a hard code?

Comment: I didnt understand sorry. #inputEmail is called a template reference in Angular. And this one of the ways how you can query elements/components from the template (Html) to code behind (TS). Make a search by angular template reference on google, maybe it will help you.

Comment: listen what I am trying to do is: there is no #inputEmail. instead I have an array or object and use ngfor to create <div>s with dynamic template ref like this:
<div ngfor="let kk of my-object" #kk>
then  in ts get them like this:
viewchild(fisrt) first;
WHICH "first" is the first value in my array: my-object=['first','sec']   For Example

Comment: like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016596/angular-5-access-divs-list-using-viewchildren

Comment: so I did wrong. but your answer in comment above was totally correct and matches with my will. I appreciate you