# How to show overlay when clicking on a menu item?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to show an overlay when clicking on a menu item (Example: clicking on item 1, item 2 or item 3). So far I have this button (**Click me**) that when you click on it it shows an overlay right below it. I want to have the same functionality when clicking on any menu item. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-v1-5qq2cq?file=app%2Fhello.component.html)

```
<p-menubar [model]="menuItems"></p-menubar>
<p-overlayPanel #op>
 Content
</p-overlayPanel>
<br/><br/>
<button type="text" pButton label="Click me" (click)="op.toggle($event)"></button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChild` decorator to get [OverlayPanel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel) instance and simply call `toggle` method on it:

**component.ts**

```typescript
@ViewChild('op') op: OverlayPanel;

toggleOverlay = ({ originalEvent }) => this.op.toggle(originalEvent);

menuItems: Array<MenuItem> = [
  {
    label: 'item 1',
    command: this.toggleOverlay,
  }, {
    label: 'item 2',
    command: this.toggleOverlay,
  }, {
    label: 'item 3',
    command: this.toggleOverlay,
  }
];

// or
menuItems2 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
  .map(item => ({ label: item, command: ({ originalEvent }) => this.op.toggle(originalEvent)}))
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-v1-uzrzut?file=app/hello.component.ts)**

See also:

- [What are all the valid selectors for ViewChild and ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162473/what-are-all-the-valid-selectors-for-viewchild-and-contentchild)

Comment: How would you show different content for each item? for example: Show "Red" for item 1, "Green" for item 2, and "Black" for item 3? Can you please update your code with that?

Comment: One option is to have several overlays https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-v1-fyxijf?file=app/hello.component.ts another option is having dynamic content for overlay https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-v1-1tjjpl?file=app/hello.component.html

Comment: Thank you so much bro!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MenuBar` for same behaviour or any other `menu` based option in `prime-ng`

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menubar