# In Angular, how do I insert specific component instances without using directives/templates?

Tags: angular, angular-components

So, let's say I have a component, `ExampleComponent`, that builds a `QueryList` of `SomeOtherComponent` components in its content view.

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, QueryList} from '@angular/core'
import {SomeOtherComponent}                    from '../some-other-component/some-other-component.component'

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    @ContentChildren(SomeOtherComponent)
    someOtherComponents: QueryList<SomeOtherComponent>
}
```

In its template, I have an NgFor that should insert a `<hr />` element after each one.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let component of someOtherComponents">
    <!-- put component here -->
    <hr />
</ng-container>
```

So that, for example, this (in some other component):

```
<app-example>
    <app-some-other-component>blablabla</app-some-other-component>
    <app-some-other-component>hello world</app-some-other-component>
    <app-some-other-component>testing</app-some-other-component>
</app-example>
```

Would result in this (in the HTML):

```
<app-example>
    <app-some-other-component>blablabla</app-some-other-component>
    <hr />
    <app-some-other-component>hello world</app-some-other-component>
    <hr />
    <app-some-other-component>testing</app-some-other-component>
    <hr />
</app-example>
```

However, this is where the problem shows up. How do I insert that `SomeOtherComponent` instance? `ng-content`'s `select` attribute doesn't support component instances, [CDK portals](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) don't like me, I don't want to create some complicated solution using templates and require the user to wrap all of their children in templates... What do I do?

To clarify: I do NOT want to create `SomeOtherComponent` instances. I want to do something similar to `<ng-content select="app-some-other-component">`, but instead insert a specific INSTANCE (like one inside the [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) returned by [`ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren)). I also don't want to use a directive/template (like putting `*thisDirectiveIMadeForJustOneComponentWhichMakesItRequireBeingPlacedInItsOwnModule` on all children).

Note: There are other ways to insert horizontal rules after components, and feel free to mention those, just make sure to answer the question too. This is just an example.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title to make it more clear, this is my third version and I'm still not sure if this is good enough.

Comment: You can use a directive for this, you have to add the directive name to each component though, see [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ek8soc).

Answer (score 7):

your question is "how do I insert specific component instances?" but what i understand from your explanation is that, you want to add lines just under the **already inserted** component instances via `ng-content`. Because you already have a `QueryList` of elements returned by `ContentChildren`.

From this point on we need to understand one important thing about ViewContainerRef;

1. [ViewContainerRef section of this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

> What’s interesting is that Angular doesn’t insert views inside the element, but appends them after the element bound to ViewContainer.

So if we can access to `ViewContainerRef`'s of elements in our `QueryList` we can easily append new elements to those elements. And we can access `ViewContainerRef` s of elements by using [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450805/what-is-the-read-parameter-in-viewchild-for) metadata property of `ContentChildren` query;

```js
@ContentChildren(SomeOtherComponent, { descendants: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) someOtherComponents: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

since we have `ViewContainerRef`s of our elements we can easily append new elements to these by using [createEmbeddedView()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createembeddedview)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild("templateToAppend", {static: true}) templateToAppend: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChildren(SomeOtherComponent, { descendants: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) someOtherComponents: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.someOtherComponents.forEach(ap => ap.createEmbeddedView(this.templateToAppend));
  }
}
```

template

```html
<ng-content></ng-content>

<ng-template #templateToAppend>
    <hr style="color: blue"/>
</ng-template>
```

demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdxjon?file=src/app/example/example.component.ts)

by utilizing this approach to create a directive in order to achive your requirement of having something similar to `<ng-content select="app-some-other-component">`

we can create a directive that takes a `TemplateRef` as `@Input()` and appends it to the `ViewContainerRef`

```js
export class CustomAppendable { }

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyCustomAppender]'
})
export class MyCustomAppenderDirective {
  @ContentChildren(CustomAppendable, { descendants: true, read: ViewContainerRef }) appendables: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
  @Input() appMyCustomAppender: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.appendables.forEach(ap => ap.createEmbeddedView(this.appMyCustomAppender));
    });
  }
}
```

with this approach, in order not to create tight coupling between our `SomeOtherComponent` and our directive we make our components somehow generic by creating a common type `CustomAppendable` and use it as an alias for the components that we want to query in `ContentChildren`

**NOTE:** i couldn't find a way to make `ContentChildren` query work with template selectors. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167289/1209097) we can use `ContentChildren` with template reference variables or Component Types. that's why i created the alias.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-other-component',
  templateUrl: './some-other-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-other-component.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: CustomAppendable, useExisting: SomeOtherComponent }]
})
export class SomeOtherComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

also with this approach we don't need the container component and apply our directive any element.

```html
<div [appMyCustomAppender]="templateToAppend">
  <app-some-other-component>underlined</app-some-other-component>
  <app-some-other-component>underlined</app-some-other-component>
  <app-some-other-component2>not underlined</app-some-other-component2>
  <br />
  <app-some-other-component2>not underlined</app-some-other-component2>
</div>
<br />
<app-some-other-component>but not underlined!</app-some-other-component>

<ng-template #templateToAppend>
  <hr  style="color: red"/>
  <br />
</ng-template>
```

demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjczea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-custom-appender.directive.ts)

i am hoping that i was able to understand your requirements correctly and all these are helpful somehow :)

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of your question it sounds like you want to dynamically insert components. This can be done by pushing the amount of `SomeOtherComponent`'s you want into an array then inside your `ngFor` you create the someOtherComponent like so:

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, QueryList} from '@angular/core'
import {SomeOtherComponent}                    from '../some-other-component/some-other-component.component'

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    someOtherComponents: any[];
    constructor(){
    this.someOtherComponents.push({data: "insert_stuff_here"});
    this.someOtherComponents.push({data: "insert_stuff_here"})
    }
}
```

Then in your ngFor

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let component of someOtherComponents">
    <someOtherComponent [possibleInputHere]="component.data"></someOtherComponent>
    <hr />
</ng-container>
```

I hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: I tihnk the idea was to be able to have different kinds of components inside the array oO

Comment: I clarified in the question, here's the part I added: To clarify: I do NOT want to create `SomeOtherComponent` instances. I want to do something similar to `<ng-content select="app-some-other-component">`, but instead insert a specific INSTANCE (like one inside the [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) returned by [`ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren)).