# nativeElement of ViewChildren's first is undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to access `ViewChildren`'s native elements => `HTMLElements`, but I keep getting `undefined` response when I do so. Take a look:

list.html

```
..
<app-element #someElement *ngFor="let element of elements"  [someinput]="someinput"></app-element>
..
```

list.ts

```
  @ViewChildren("someElement") someElements:QueryList<ElementRef>;

  @HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"]) 
  resize(event){
    console.log(event);
    console.log((this.someElements.first)); //returns ElementComponent as expected
    console.log((this.someElements.first.nativeElement)); // nativeElement appears to be undefined

  }
```

I've used `ViewChildren` numerous times. However, this time it does not work as expected. Is it because `ViewChild` is an angular component? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would specify what I want to get

```
@ViewChildren("someElement", { read: ElementRef }) someElements:QueryList<ElementRef>;
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       please give me ElementRef instead of component instance
```

See also

- [How to get reference of the component associated with ElementRef in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203)

Comment: There you can find link to one more great answer) I suggest you reading it in your free time