# Angular material: control ripple effect from code

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I know I can trigger the ripple effect on divs, like in this [demo](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview#manual-ripples)

But this only works for the first element with the ripple directive. If I have two elements with the directive, like this:

```
<div matRipple #rippleOne>
   rippleOne
</div>
<div matRipple #rippleTwo>
   rippleTwo
</div>
```

Now how do I only trigger the second ripple? Tried this:

```
@ViewChild(MatRipple)
rippleTwo: MatRipple;
...
this.rippleTwo.launch({});
```

Which won't work.

Also

```
@ViewChild('rippleTwo')
```

won't work. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` option should do the trick:

```
@ViewChild('rippleTwo', { read: MatRipple })
rippleTwo: MatRipple;
```

See also:

- [How to get reference of the component associated with ElementRef in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203)