# Access nativeElement from projected directive

Tags: angular

I have a component which is meant to wrap Reactive Form controls. I want to standardize those controls, requiring minimun amount of client code and injecting stuff like custom CSS classes.

At the same time, I don't want to force clients to add yet another directive to control elements. Hence, I would like to hook into **elements that already use the FormControlName directive**.

Here's what I want my client code to look like:

```html
<my-form-control>
  <input formControlName="whatever" />
</my-form-control>
```

And here's what my component looks like so far:

```ts
import { Component, AfterContentInit, Input, ContentChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-control',
  template: `<ng-content select="[formControlName]"></ng-content>`
})
export class MyFormControlComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(FormControlName, {static: false}) directive: FormControlName;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Ok, I have the directive. Now I need access to
    // the native element somehow to add the class like so:
    const nativeElement = this.directive.<<< GRAB_ELEMENT_SOMEHOW??? >>>();
    this.renderer.addClass(nativeElement, 'my-control');
  }
}
```

I've put together a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4rz3c) of what I'm trying to do:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `read` option to your `ContentChild` decorator:

```
@ContentChild(FormControlName, {static: false, read: ElementRef }) directive: ElementRef;

..
ngAfterContentInit() {
  const nativeElement = this.directive.nativeElement;
  this.renderer.addClass(nativeElement, 'my-control');
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32a6ic?file=src/app/my-form-control.component.ts)**

See also:

- [How to get reference of the component associated with ElementRef in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203)