# ElementRef of row in mat-table

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

my question is that is there a way so that I can get element reference of a particular row in mat-table. I am getting the data from an API. I want to display popover over a row in mat-table and popover requires element reference or HTML element to get attached to. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is a way for almost anything. Share your code, please

Comment: @Belegnar yes Sure My popover functions looks like this: showPopover(template: TemplateRef<any>, target: HTMLElement | ElementRef<any>, position: string, backdrop: boolean): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.popoverService.open(template, target, position, backdrop, {}), 200);
  }  I am building a website tour. I have a table and lets say I have a button next in popovers when I click on it it shows the next popover. So when I click next I the popover should be displayed at particular row. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may no longer need this answer, but I had a hard time tracking it down, so I'm going to leave the solution here for others who were performing the same searches as I.

Typically, you can access DOM elements by using Angular's `ViewChildren` decorator. However in this instance, your table rows use the `mat-row` directive, which means that `ViewChildren` will instead return the Angular Material MatRow objects, with no (clean) path to the rendered rows. However, you can configure `ViewChildren` to explicitly pass the `ElementRef` instead (which I discovered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909203/2141290)).

So add a template variable reference to your row elements in your HTML file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <!-- // #tableBodyRow below is your new template reference variable -->
  <tr #tableBodyRow mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <!-- // Rest of your table definition here -->
</table>
```

And then in your `component.ts` file, use `ViewChildren` to access those elements, indicating that you want the DOM element specifically:

```
// The second parameter to the ViewChildren decorator is the key to getting
// the DOM elements
//
// The first parameter must match the template reference variable name you
// indicated in your HTML template.
@ViewChildren('tableBodyRow', {read: ElementRef}) renderedBodyRows: QueryList<
    ElementRef<HTMLTableRowElement>
  >;
```

You can now access the DOM elements created by `MatTable`. 2 caveats:

1. Items referenced by the `ViewChildren` decorator are only accessible after `ngAfterViewInit` has run - see the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). If you don't know what I'm talking about here, wrap the `renderedBodyRows` variable in a getter function and expect it to return `undefined` while your table is being rendered.
2. The rows returned by this process do not appear to be in the order they are displayed in the DOM. If order/indices are important to you, make sure to perform some type of sorting based on the row content related to your dataSource object. If you're stuck, try assigning a class or other property to the rows in your `mat-row` definition based on the index.

Answer (score -1):

In `mat-table`, when you use **row** as:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Here, **row** is the `ElementRef`, you can pass **row** in `click` or `hover` event, however you want.

Comment: thanx for your response. Actually I am building a website tour. I don't want to show popover when the user hovers or click. I need element reference already so that when the user clicks on next it takes it to that particular row.

Comment: when you show column values you use `*matCellDef="let element"`, you can pass 'element' to your button click function.

Comment: This isn't correct. *row* is a reference to a variable - the current item in the *dataSource* input to `mat-table`. It is not the instance of the `HTMLTableRowElement` generated in the DOM, which is what the Angular `ElementRef` object contains.