# Can't access nativeElement on my component. Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript

Ultimately I want to use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method to detect the bottom of my component and am using the `@ViewChild` directive to do so.  Normally in the past when doing this we need to access the `nativeElement` of the element we target with the `@ViewChild` however it doesn't seem to work on components.

As of right now I'm doing it this way which works

***template***

```
<section #intro>
    <intro />
</section>
```

***component***

```
export class HomePageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('intro', {static: true}) Intro?: ElementRef;
  
  // irrelevant code

  private detectIntroHeight():number{
    return this.Intro?.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  }
}
```

This code works.  However if I do this

***template***

```
<intro #intro />
```

***component***

```
export class HomePageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('intro', {static: true}) Intro?: IntroComponent;
  
  // irrelevant code

  private detectIntroHeight():number{
    return this.Intro?.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  }
}
```

I get an error saying nativeElement doesn't exist on IntroComponent.  I've tried making it of type `ElementRef<IntroComponent>` and got the same error.  I also removed nativeElement just leaving the `getBoundingClientRect()` method and got the same error saying it doesn't exist on IntroComponent.

Is there a way to make that work directly on my component without having to wrap it in an HTML element?  I'd rather not have to wrap it just so I can detect where its located on the page.

Here's a basic [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kgfu4n?file=src%2Fmain.ts) that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: What is Intro markup? How the component is defined. probably it is not a dom element, while section is and can be accessed with nativelement and it has height, etc

Comment: I think, reading it's ElementRef should work. See ViewChild docs.

Comment: when I do `ElementRef` without the `<IntroComponent>` reference I get an error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')`.

Comment: In the case of `<intro #intro />`, you should try `@ViewChild('intro', {read: ElementRef}, {static: true}) introElement: ElementRef;` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909203/1009922). If it works, we could mark your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39908967/1009922).

Comment: THAT WORKS!!!!  However instead of having `read` and `static` in two separate objects, I passed them in the same object as `{read: ElementRef, static: true}`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the same but with @ContentChild and make sure you don’t call the method before rendering is done?

Comment: I just tried it according to what the documentation shows and not getting any results.  When I `console.log()` the results I get `undefined`.  However the example they give in the docs is on a `@Directive` rather than a component, how would I need to set it up?

Comment: Can you try calling the method from ngAfterViewInit - any of the queries above. Is it still undefined? Please create a stackblitz and I will help you:)

Comment: Yes even with `ngAfterViewInit` I get the same error.  However when wrapped in an HTML element I don't have any issues.

Comment: I just updated my post with a stackblitz.  The problem occurs with both standalone components and ones imported into a module which I included in the demo.